# How to handle Big Integer from Dataframe to SQL

Tags: python, sql, biginteger, bigint

The StaffIdent and FirmIdent in the dataframe DF_JSON are big integers. Eg. StaffIdent 15423992539793905091
I want to convert the data from dataframe to SQL, it is OK when I treat StaffIndent and FirmIndent as strings and merge the new data with current data in TEST table in SQL. This works:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, types
import os
import logging
import json
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy 
import pandasql as ps

def upload_data(SQLServer,SQLDatabase,JSON_file):
    Table_Name='TEST'
    engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://{0}/{1}?driver=SQL Server?Trusted_Connection=yes'.format(SQLServer,SQLDatabase))
    i=0
    for JSON_file in os.listdir('Data/'+Table_Name):
        logging.info('Debug: Reading file JSON and inserting into database: {0}'.format(JSON_file))
        JSON = json.load(open('Data/'+Table_Name+'/'+JSON_file))
        DF_JSON=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(JSON,dtype=object)
        DF_JSON = DF_JSON.astype(str)

        try:
            if i==0:
                DF_JSON.to_sql(Table_Name,engine,if_exists='replace',chunksize=50,index=False,dtype={'StaffIdent':sqlalchemy.types.String, 'FirmIdent':sqlalchemy.types.String})
            else:
                DF_JSON.to_sql(Table_Name,engine,if_exists='append',chunksize=50,index=False,dtype={'StaffIdent':sqlalchemy.types.String, 'FirmIdent':sqlalchemy.types.String})
            print('Successfully')
        except Exception as ErrorMessage:
            logging.info(': Error occured when inserting records into DB: '+ErrorMessage+'.')

        return DF_JSON
        logging.info('Successfully uploaded JSON to SQL {}'.format(JSON_file))
```

The problem is, converting them as strings is not an efficient way because the StaffIndent and FirmIndent in TEST in SQL are originally numeric. My question: How to handle BigInt and treat them as numbers right in to_sql step?

When replace String with BigInteger:

```
        try:
            if i==0:
                DF_JSON.to_sql(Table_Name,engine,if_exists='replace',chunksize=50,index=False,dtype={'StaffIdent':sqlalchemy.types.BigInteger, 'FirmIdent':sqlalchemy.types.BigInteger})
            else:
                DF_JSON.to_sql(Table_Name,engine,if_exists='append',chunksize=50,index=False,dtype={'StaffIdent':sqlalchemy.types.BigInteger, 'FirmIdent':sqlalchemy.types.BigInteger})
```

An error:

```
DataError: (pyodbc.DataError) ('22003', '[22003] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint. (8115) (SQLExecDirectW); [22003] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)')
```

Using Decimal sounds good but No, the dtype must be numeric & integer when come to SQL

```
                DF_JSON.to_sql(Table_Name,engine,if_exists='replace',chunksize=50,index=False,dtype={'StaffIdent':sqlalchemy.types.DECIMAL(38,0), 'FirmIdent':sqlalchemy.types.DECIMAL(38,0)})
            else:
                DF_JSON.to_sql(Table_Name,engine,if_exists='append',chunksize=50,index=False,dtype={'StaffIdent':sqlalchemy.types.DECIMAL(38,0), 'FirmIdent':sqlalchemy.types.DECIMAL(38,0)})
```

Answer (score 1):

My StaffIdent and FirmIdent include 20 digits/each (Eg. StaffIdent 15423992539793905091) which is bigger than max BigInt (19 digits only. 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 in 8 Bytes) So I must find another one which is even bigger than BigInt. NUMBERIC(38,0) is the answer.

BigInt goes up 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 in 8 Bytes

NUMBERIC(38,0) goes up 17 Bytes

Document https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-numeric.html

I refer the suggestions in this page https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=129388

After all, we're gonna have:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, types
import os
import logging
import json
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy 
import pandasql as ps

def upload_data(SQLServer,SQLDatabase,JSON_file):
    print('Debug...')
    Table_Name='TEST'
    engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://{0}/{1}?driver=SQL Server?Trusted_Connection=yes'.format(SQLServer,SQLDatabase))
    i=0
    for JSON_file in os.listdir('Data/'+Table_Name):
        logging.info('Debug: Reading file JSON and inserting into database: {0}'.format(JSON_file))
        JSON = json.load(open('Data/'+Table_Name+'/'+JSON_file))
        DF_JSON=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(JSON,dtype=object)
        DF_JSON = DF_JSON.astype(str)

        try:
            if i==0:
                DF_JSON.to_sql(Table_Name,engine,if_exists='replace',chunksize=50,index=False,dtype={'StaffIdent':sqlalchemy.types.NUMERIC(38,0), 'FirmIdent':sqlalchemy.types.NUMERIC(38,0)})
            else:
                DF_JSON.to_sql(Table_Name,engine,if_exists='append',chunksize=50,index=False,dtype={'StaffIdent':sqlalchemy.types.NUMERIC(38,0), 'FirmIdent':sqlalchemy.types.NUMERIC(38,0)})
            print('Successfully')
        except Exception as ErrorMessage:
            print('Error')
            print(ErrorMessage)

        return DF_JSON
```

This will return dtype of StaffIdent and FirmIdent as numberic in SQL